# Change path of gapi.client.request from relative to absolute

Tags: google-api-js-client

I want to use a refresh token to generate an access token. So I am making a gapi.client.request as shown below. I want to use host as 'accounts.google.com' (my actual path is 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token') but the request is sent with path 'content.googleapis.com/o/oauth2/token'. The main problem is that gapi uses a ***relative* url** in the path parameter so even if i put the full path in 'path' it interpretes it starting with 'content.googleapis.com' followed by 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' which is obviously not even a valid url. So how do I set the path to be absolute rather than relative?

```
gapi.client.request({
          'path':'/o/oauth2/token',
          'method':'POST',
          'params':{'rerfresh_token':refreshToken,'client_id':clientId,'client_secret':clientSecret,'grant_type':'refresh_token'}
          });
      request.execute();
```